# Another jQuery mobile redirect

Tags: jquery, redirect, mobile

I have a site that uses the odd `header()` PHP command after a form submit to redirect to another page. jQuery mobile does the redirect no problem and shows the correct page.

What it doesn't do is update the 'data-role="page"' div; it only seems to update anything inside the 'data-role="content"' div. This has the effect of confusing the site as to where it is. If I hit refresh on the redirected page (page 2), I end up getting the page with the form reloaded (page 1).

After much searching, I've figured out if I use 'data-ajax="false"' on the form, this fixes the problem. Question is, is this the best way to do it or is there a way to perform a redirect while staying within ajax? Can I change the `header()` to something else more jQuery mobile/ajax friendly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way besides ajax false that I know to fix this is to add `data-url='redirect_url_here'` to the div with `data-role='page'`.